# Is Tizen possible on Raspberry Pi 400?

Tags: tizen

I thought the Raspberry Pi and Raspberry Pi 400 were the same, right?

I tried to use tizen referring to the following url, but it didn't work.

https://docs.tizen.org/platform/developing/flashing-rpi/

Is it correct that the tizen image works on Raspberry Pi 400?

Comment: Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Not at all, I couldn't reach uboot.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have rpi400 target, so I can't test with tizen on rpi400. AFAIK, tizen rpi4 image can be used to rpi400 board. Because it's using same u-boot/kernel, except device-tree.
Which tizen image did you use? Could you share more information? (etc. tizen version, boot log or fail log.)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I don't remember exactly, but it was one of December, 2021 tizen 6.5 images.
There's a little update on this...
I think the problem that booting does not start at all is related to the firmware in the Tizen image.
After putting the new firmware into the Tizen image from the latest Raspbian image, it booted up.
However, the display manager did not seem to work properly, and it rebooted.

Comment: After 13th of Dec,  some patches is updated on u-boot. Before updated, it is used to device-tree as static. So it can't support other boards. Because it was  considered only rpi4.  And we're preparing to update the latest firmware from rpi-firmware. Which firmware version did you use?